# Альбомная ориентация при печати по умолчанию

Tags: html, javascript, css

ННужно выставить альбомную ориентацию при печати страницы из браузера по умолчанию. Печать страницы с помощью функции window.print(). На просторах гугла дают только вариант с директивами [[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) и @page наподобие

```
@media print {
@page {size:landscape;
}
}
```

Однако данный вариант не работает в принципе. Есть вероятность, что не поддерживается в css3 или браузерами. Есть ли другая возможность установить альбомную ориентацию по умолчанию при печати? Спасибо.

Comment: В каком браузере не работает? У меня на работе Chromium, там этот код работает вполне себе. Более точный кусок css кода смогу привести завтра